# Swift xCode 6.4 - using a variable generated by a tableview controller in a second view controller

Tags: ios, swift, variables, viewcontroller

I am am googling around the whole day for a probably simple question but I do not get it right. Hopefully someone can help me.

I have a tableview controller with one prototype cell containing three custom labels.
When I run the app the table view controller will generate about 150 tableview cells with content parsed form a csv-file.

When I click on one of these cells the user will be forwarded two a second view controller showing some additional infotext for his cell selection.
During the same time the user is clicking the tabelview cell a variable will be updated to the corresponding tableview-row-number (e.g. 150 for the last tableview cell.
Now I want to use this variable as reference text within the text shown in the second view controller.

The variable in the tableview controller is "rowSelectedFromList" and will be set by the following code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var rowSelectedFromList: String

    rowSelectedFromList = rowOfItems[indexPath.row].customlabel3!
    println(rowSelectedFromList)
}
```

The "println" is just for checking if it works correctly and it does.

The question is how can I use the variable "rowSelectedFromList" in the second view controller?

Appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Just regarding your question title: iOS 6.4? Maybe you mean Xcode 6.4. As far as I'm aware you can't use Swift on iOS versions prior to 7.0

Comment: You are right, just changed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code which is working for me is a mixture Phoen1xUK and glyuck answers.
I put both together and ended up with this working version:

For the FirstViewController:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SecondControllerSegue" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
          let rowSelectedFromList = rowOfItems[indexPath.row].customlabel3
          (segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController).rowTransferedFromList = rowSelectedFromList
        }
    }
}
```

In the SecondViewController I set up the variable as follows:

```
var rowTransferedFromList: String!
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to put something in `prepareForSegue` as well as a variable in your second view controller. So in your table view controller:

```
var variableToPass: String!

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    variableToPass = rowOfItems[indexPath.row].customlabel3!.text
    performSegueWithIdentifier("SecondControllerSegue", sender: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SecondControllerSegue" {
        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
        destinationController.passedVariable = variableToPass
    } 
}
```

And in your second view controller you'll want to add the variable that the value will be passed to:

```
var passedVariable: String!
```

You can, of course, choose to replace the variable with whatever type you wish to send :)

Comment: Thanks. In general it is working but I have an issue with the second view controller now: it will open "twice" by sliding thru and I have to click also the "back" button twice to get back to the first view controller. This looks bad. From these two pages the second slide is indicating the actual (correct) row number from the page in-between the row number from the selection the time before. If I do not run the the first function performSegueWithIdentifier("SecondControllerSegue", sender: nil) the behavior of the table is correct, but the value is always the one from the click before

Comment: Hmm it sounds like you have some other function/action calling the change of controller - when creating the segue, don't ctrl click and drag from the table cell to the new view controller. Instead ctrl click and drag from the controller itself to your second view controller to create a manual segue. You can remove the other one.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your custom logic in `prepareForSegue` like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? YourSecondController,
            indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        controller.someVariable = rowOfItems[indexPath.row].customlabel3!
    }
}
```

Replace YourSecondController with class name for second view controller.

Don't forget to create IBOutlet for your UITableView and name it `tableView`.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain what you mean with this: "Don't forget to create IBOutlet for your UITableView and name it tableView". I know how to create a IBO for a label or button, but how do I do it for a variable or a UITableView?

Answer (score 0):

Good question if you want sort this problem plz follow below code:

```
class ViewController {
     var cvDataArray = cells = NSMutableArray.new()
    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        cvDataArray.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({(obj: AnyObject, idx: Int, stop: Bool) in            var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("")
            cell.textLabel.text = obj["title"]
            cells.addObject(cell)

        })
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cells.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return cells.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var cell: UITableViewCell = cells.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    }
}
```